# SQL Query for Conditional Join

Tags: sql, join

I have the following 3 tables. I need a single query to select from table 1 if either a matching record is found in table 2 or table 3.

Table 1: 
RecordID,
GroupID,
Name

Table 2:
RecordID (which is Table1.RecordID),
SubID,
AFlag

Table 3:
GroupID (which is Table1.GroupID),
SubID,
AFlag

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly straight forward, just use left joins and match on the final joined table existence of IDs

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t2
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.RecordID = t2.RecordID
    LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.GroupID = t3.GroupID
    WHERE t2.SubID IS NOT NULL OR t3.SubID IS NOT NULL
```

That should get you much closer to your end goal

Answer (score 1):

bryan posts so fast!
alternatively...

```
select * 
from table1
where (recordid in (select recordid from table2)  ) 
OR (recordid in (select recordid from table3) )
```

Comment: +1 . . . Your answer is better.  Bryan's might produce duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic query would look a little something like this, I think:

```
SELECT *
    FROM Table1 T1
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Table2 T2 WHERE T1.RecordId = T2.RecordId )
        OR EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Table3 T3 WHERE T1.GroupId = T3.GroupId )
```